# git clone fail : which is about setting certificate

Tags: git, certificate, setting

Whenever I git clone,it appeared like this.
And I could't clone anything from the github now.
Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set environment variable, to allow access to server

Answer (score 0):

git config --global http.sslverify "false"